# How to change index of "arguments[index].click()" in Selenium WebDriver (Eclipse)

Tags: javascript, selenium

Help me change index of "arguments[index].click()" when used javascript to click hidden button in Selenium WebDriver (Eclipse)

this is my code:

```js
public page_ProductInfo Buy(int i)  {
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
  WebElement ButtonBought = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
    "//button[@class='c-quick-buy__button c-button c-button_size_big c-button_color_old-orange  c-button_js_inited']"));
   String index=Integer.toString(i);
  
   String script = "arguments["+index+"].click();";
   
   js.executeScript(script, ButtonBought);
  
  return new page_ProductInfo(driver);

 }
```

And error message:

```js
FAILED: f
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `WebElement ButtonBought = driver.findElement(By.xpath(`, so ButtonBought is a single element, I guess `js.executeScript` works with `arguments[0]`?

Please try to find list of elements instead:

```
List<WebElement> ButtonBought = driver.findElements(By.xpath(
```